# Is there a way to filter an array with specific number of returned items in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, filter, ecma

For example, I only want to get two items that satisfy the filter condition.

filter() then slice(2) will iterate all items which is really a waste while find() can only return one item.

Is there any way to specify the number of returned items that satisfy the filter condition? except writing for loop by myself.

Comment: using forEach, throw error when get two item.

Answer (score 0):

`reduce` should do the job, consider the following example

```js
[1, 2, 3, 4].reduce((acc, n) => n > 2 ? [...acc, n] : acc, []) // results [3, 4]
```

Comment: While this answer should work it’s worth pointing out that this hits the same “problem” as using `filter()` and `map()` as it also iterates over the whole array which OP views as “*wasteful*.”

Comment: Actually, I don't think that JavaScript (and its variants) has such a lazy evaluating or short-circuit mechanism. So maybe the only choice that is not *wasteful* is for-loop.

Comment: Don’t misunderstand me, I have no problem with your answer, I just wanted to raise the point that it may run into OP’s objections. Personally, while I accept that some extra work is being done I’d accept that “cost” for additional functionality at a later date (wanting to find the maximum or minimum values for example).

Comment: Maybe you're right. I'm now confused about what OP what to achieve, either performance optimization or just syntactically refactoring. For the former one, this answer is just against the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop and break. You could make a helper method to do this:

```js
const found = [];
for (let i = 0; i < sourceArray.length; i++) {
   if (whatever) found.push(sourceArray[i];
   if (found.length >= 2) break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write a helper function that takes in your array, a count number, and a predicate function, similar to how array.filter works. Return true if the item should be included.

```js
function filterCount(array, count, predicate) {
  const elements = [];

  for (const el in array) {
    if (predicate(el)) {
      elements.push(el);
    }
    if (elements.length >= count) {
      break;
    }
  }

  return elements;
}

const test = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

const onlyTwo = filterCount(test, 2, (number) => number >= 5);
console.log(onlyTwo)
```